# How to make .vbs read/write protected?

Tags: vbscript

Is there any way to make a .vbs file Read only,so that no one rather a specific person can read the content or change the content? But only can double click on that file to start its execution. I will set up a Main.vbs into which I would put the below

```
 Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
 oShell.run "A.VBS", 1, True
 oShell.run "B.VBS", 1, True
 oShell.run "C.VBS", 1, True
 oShell.run "D.VBS", 1, True
```

The user will click only on the main.vbs to start the execution. All the .vbs I want to be Read/write protected. is my thought possible in practice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't read it you can't run it.

You can set permissions so that no other person (except administrators) can change the file, but you can't prevent people from being able to read the file if they're supposed to be able to run it.

Comment: So should I need to set the permissions by manually or it can be done via the windows command. one more thing to ask can I make those files as .EXE?

Comment: You can set the permissions either manually in the GUI or with a command. The effect will be the same. As for converting VBScript to an EXE: please use a search engine.

Comment: any reference would you like to refer for making `.vbs` to an `.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Some other options to consider.  The script can be encoded with the Microsoft Script Encoder.  This will make it unreadable.  One download link here (can't find the official Microsoft download link) http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/Microsoft-Script-Encoder.shtml. Of course, it is possible for people to decode the file using the appropriate tool.

Another option is to digitally sign the script with a code-signing certificate.  This will still allow it to be viewed, but it will not be able to be modified without breaking the digital signature.

Or even encode the script then digitally sign it.

Comment: If i decode those script,will it perform the tasks for which they have been created.And is the decoder software also needs to be installed to others PC for whom i made these. Because those are the scripts will be running globally!

Comment: There is no need to decode the scripts.  The script engine (WScript or CScript) will automatically decode and run it.  When encoded, just make the extension `.vbe` and it will work without anything else needing to be done.

Comment: The problem with the Microsoft Script Encoder is that the algorithm for protecting scripts is very weak.  Details on the algorithm and examples on how to decode were published years ago (http://wp.daveheavyindustries.com/2011/04/28/decoding-windows-script-encoder-encoded-scripts/).

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of this is to protect your code, then you can always make an executable file.